How to find dropdown name in HTML code for Selenium's Select class?
I want to download the CSV data shown at the end of the page using Python:
https://www.cboe.com/delayed_quotes/spx/quote_table/
Specifically, before downloading the data, I need Python to select the dropdowns Option Range and Expirations to 'All'
I have the following code to access the website via Python, which works fine.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.cboe.com/delayed_quotes/spx/quote_table')

html = driver.page_source

I want to use the Selenium select function, but I am unable to find the id of the two dropdowns in the HTML code.
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "????")


First things first, you cannot use Selenium's Select class if the dropdown does not have a <select> or a <option> element. Refer the link to know what you can and what you cannot using Select class.
Your target HTML does not have a <select> node for the targeted dropdown. Hence you need to interact with the dropdowns in some other way.
Refer the below working code with explanation in commented lines:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://www.cboe.com/delayed_quotes/spx/quote_table")

# Click on I Agree cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='I agree']"))).click()

# Below 2 lines will send text 'All' to 'Options Range' text box and performs click on key TAB
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "select_5"))).send_keys("All")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "select_5"))).send_keys(Keys.TAB)

# Below 2 lines will send text 'All' to 'Expiration' text box and performs click on key TAB
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "select_7"))).send_keys("All")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "select_7"))).send_keys(Keys.TAB)

# Click on View Chain button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='View Chain']"))).click()

# Click on download button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@download='spx_quotedata.csv']"))).click()
time.sleep(5)


works good - thank you.
However, I forgot to mention (my bad) that after interacting with the dropdowns, the browser needs to click on the View Chain button to load the newly selected settings.

Code updated to click View Chian. What should I do when someone answers my question?
